# How to create a Subpartition on Date with an existing Partiion by range (also on Date) in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

So I am on Oracle 10g and I am trying to create a PARTITION AND SUBPARTITION on an existing Materialized View.

The current partition syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST
NOLOGGING 
PARTITION BY RANGE(TEST_DATE)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE(MONTH(TEST_DATE)) 
      ( PARTITION A0 VALUES LESS THAN ('01-01-2015')
       ,PARTITION A1 VALUES LESS THAN ('01-01-2016')
       ,PARTITION A2 VALUES LESS THAN ('01-01-2017')
       ...)
AS 
SELECT....
```

I get a syntax error saying that I am missing a right parenthesis, I've been trying for a full day now trying to fix this up and looking online. Can anyone help prod me in the right direction? Perhaps I can Partition on Year and SubPartition on Month?

Comment: What is the purpose of having subpartition per months of yearly partitions? This looks really useless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, unless you make some hacks with virtual columns.

Why not simply make interval partition by months?

```
...
PARTITION BY RANGE (TEST_DATE) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
(PARTITION A_INITIAL VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2014-01-01')
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a partition by year and then a subpartition by month? If so would someone be able to help me with the syntax? Thanks in advance